# Performance tests with hibernate and jdbc

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, testing, jdbc

Good afternoon,

I'm developing my serach on university a comparison between Hibernate and JDBC,
and a major focus of the work is on performance.

One question that I am being charged too is related to HOW I will conduct these performance tests.

Well, this is my work briefly, owning two methods that make queries to the database aiming to seek data X,
and these queries would be written in hibernate and jdbc, and from that conduct tests on both.

Could you tell me how often are performed and evaluated how these tests?
What tools are used? Searching I found a tool that comes with the jdk called JConsole, ya think this tool could solve my problem?

Thank you:]

Answer (score 6):

I would vote to close this question, for a couple of reasons. But this is a subject that is brought very often, so, I feel compelled to answer, specially because I've spent some time thinking and doing some performance measures for Hibernate as part of my day job.

Doing performance tests and/or benchmark for Hibernate, or anything that involves database, is extremely tricky and should be done only in environments where you have a real world problem to solve (ie: an existing application). A synthetic benchmark is usually pretty much useless, as it will not give good enough answers to a wider audience. I understand that this is an academic experience, and it should be regarded as such :-) I'll try to list the main problems I've experienced:

1) Hibernate is just too fast to be accurately measured. As most of the time is spent on networking and on the database itself, it's very hard to measure *only* the time spent on Hibernate. I've used a set of tricks to extract this, including using ByteMan (http://jboss.org/byteman) to enhance the bytecode to extract the exact timings. Most of the operations that I've measured took only a few milliseconds. This means that even the slightest disturbance on the machine caused significant changes in the result. So, watch out for the standard deviation, and discard a good chunk of the "best results" and "poorest results" (20% each would be my suggestion, ending up with the 60% in the middle).

2) It's hard to choose between having a local database and a database in another machine. The reason is that you either end up not measuring Hibernate, but the Operating System's scheduler and IO if you decide to use a local database, or you end up measuring the network performance, if you decide to use a database in a separate machine.

3) Java HotSpot VM does a lot of inlining of the bytecode, optimizing it the more you use. So, you have to "warm up" the VM before taking real timings. If you do a performance test for 10 minutes, doing only a couple thousand operations, you might end up not measuring the software at its best possible performance. So, run it for some hours. Or better, run several tests, with different number of hours each: 4 hours, 8 hours and 16 hours would be good candidates.

4) Still on the "best possible performance" topic, you should fine tune Hibernate for your usage. For instance, if you have tons of memory and a fast CPU on the host running Hibernate and you choose to use a database in a separate machine, caching choices might help Hibernate gain performance. And not using caching on this scenario is not realistic ;-) Also, depending on the scenario, caching might actually hurt. So, a good knowledge of how Hibernate's 2nd-Level caching works is required.

5) Talking about caching: Hibernate has a 1st-level caching and 2nd-Level caching. The choice on whether to use caching will also affect the final result. Same for connection pooling: Hibernate does come with an internal connection pooling mechanism which should not be used for production. So, you end up measuring a component which should not be used at all. On the other hand, you'll probably not implement your own caching or connection pooling mechanism for the JDBC test. Side note: in the real world, in Java EE applications, Hibernate should be configured to consume the Application Server's connection pooling.

6) You should also be aware of JDBC features that might be used by Hibernate in the real world, like batching queries (if you do a lot of inserts, for instance). For this option, you might need to tune Hibernate to adjust it. You should also implement this on your "pure JDBC" tests. And note that there are options which might work better for some RDMBSes than others.

7) Hardware: running on your local machine is totally different than running on a real-world server. I'd personally recommend running it on several instance types on Amazon EC2, using Amazon's Linux. This way, it's easily reproducible by other interested parties. But watch also for delays inherent to virtual machines. Discarding the 20% top and bottom from point 1 should take care of this.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

jConsole will give you the ability to see what resources your application are using such as cpu usage and memory usage. What kind of metrics are you trying to test these calls for? Are you trying to see the amount of resources used or are you just trying to test overall speed?

Comment: My biggest issue would focus on speed.
Currently I am doing the speed tests with System.currentTimeMilllis () and starting the data collected, generating graphs.
However I do not know if this is the best way to conduct tests of this nature.

Comment: I was suggested to use jconsole to check the amount of memory used in queries, which I believe is their functionality, right?

Comment: yes jconsole will give you that ability to determine memory usage of your application.